# Multiple Conditions in one column

Tags: postgresql

[image]

```
-- ncid YES=21, NO=24
-- nqid ATTENDING=15, NOT ATTENDING=19
--nqid=16 what year or grade?
-- choice grade 1 to grade 6 = 29 to 36

SELECT *FROM tbl_answer WHERE nqid IN ('16', '15') and choice IN('21','29','30','31','32','35','36')
```

Should return all the members that is still studying and in grade 1 to grade 6.

Comment: If the comments "ATTENDING=15, grade 1 to grade 6 = 29 to 36" are correct, won't WHERE nqid=15 AND choice IN ('29','30','31','32',.....,'36') give you your result set?

Comment: The `ATTENDING=15` is a form of question which is in `nqid` and its answer is in `ncid` which can be `21 or 22`...It returns 0 result.

Comment: I guess if you use http://sqlfiddle.com/ and provide the SQL statements to create the table, insert a few records and expected output for that dataset, it will be better.

Comment: The image can be used as an example. All I want is to get the member if he/she attends school and in grade 1 to grade 6.

Answer (score 0):

I think from your comments what you need is

```
   SELECT *FROM tbl_answer WHERE nqid = '15' and  choice IN('29','30','31','32','35','36')
```